# Generate "select inputs" through loops in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have the following array:

```
$selects = array(
        'Select1' => array('select1_name' => array('select1_value1','select1_value1')),
        'Select2' => array('select2_name' => array('select2_value1','select2_value2'))
    );
```

I wonder how I can generate these "selects inputs" with their options through a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one cycle, which will loop through selects array and inside this cycle, you need another one, which will loop through selects. And inside this one, you need one more, which will loop through the option values:

```
$selects = array(
    'Select1' => array('select1_name' => array('select1_value1','select1_value1')),
    'Select2' => array('select2_name' => array('select2_value1','select2_value2'))
);

foreach($selects as $select) {
    foreach($select as $item) {
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($item as $value) {
            echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```html
<select>
  <option value=select1_value1>select1_value1</option>
  <option value=select1_value1>select1_value1</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value=select2_value1>select2_value1</option>
  <option value=select2_value2>select2_value2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($selects as $select) {
     foreach($select as $selectName => $value) {
          echo '<select> ';
            echo '<option>'.$selectName.'</option>';
            foreach($value as $v) {
                echo '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
            }
          echo '</select>';
     }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<select> ';
    foreach($selects as $array) {       
     foreach($array as $value) {    
                foreach($value as $v) {
                echo '<option value="'.$v.'">'.$v.'</option>';
            }}}       
   echo '</select>';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 agree :)